# multiple inbound-channel-adapter of spring integration using the same channel

Tags: spring, integration

I am using inbound-channel-adapter of spring integration. I want to poll under two different directories -one per file category- and parse the files that are located there. The code that i use is:

```
<int:channel id="inputChannel"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInOne"                        
                              directory="myDirOne"
                              auto-create-directory="true"
                              channel = "inputChannel">
    <int:poller id="one" cron="1/10 * * * * *"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInTwo"                        
                              directory="myDirTwo"
                              auto-create-directory="true"
                              channel = "inputChannel">
    <int:poller id="two" cron="1/10 * * * * *"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Both inbound-channel-adapters use the same channel. So I want to know from which inbound-channel-adapter the file was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

These are two ways that I can think of:

a. Pass each of the flows through a header enricher, add a custom header which tells you which  directory you started from, and then to the inputChannel.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInOne"                        
                              directory="myDirOne"
                              auto-create-directory="true"
                              channel = "dirOneEnricher">
    <int:poller id="one" cron="1/10 * * * * *"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="dirOneEnricher" output-channel="inputChannel">
    <int:header name="fileCategory" value="dirOneTypeCategory"/> 
</int:header-enricher>
```

..

b. Since the payload is a `java.io.File`, you can use the API's to find out which directory this file belongs to and take some action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it. I would like to ask something else. Does this configuration affect the efficiency? Is better to use different channels for each inbound-channel-adapter?